# MySQL vs PostgreSQL using various data sources for Tableau. Which is better?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-web-services

Im currently using a MySQL DB to pull/run queries injunction with Tableau. Based on the amount of data the queries are taking hours to run. Im thinking of switching to PostgreSQL but new to it. Would this be a good idea or can I optimize MySQL for my needs? I will be adding various data sources as we grow as well.

Comment: "Taking hours to run" -- usually means (*) missing index, (*) poor schema design, (*) poor query design.   Let's see all of those, maybe we can help you fix the performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer definitively without knowing: your schema, your indexes and your queries sent by Tableau.

MySQL (and MariaDB) are excellent databases for certain use cases. Postgres is excellent for most of those use cases, and also others. [*risk of generalizing alert*]: Postgres can utilize complex indexes better, and also can be finer tuned.

Your statement "*Based on the amount of data*" suggests indexes are not aligned with the info you want to pull. I know from experience, an index that supports my data pulls makes queries run like a hot knife through butter, no matter what db is used.

8 times out of 10, MySQL or Postgres would suffice. This [tableau page](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/database-query-performance) suggests a conversation with your DBA would help you.

If ***you*** are your own DBA as is often the case, I'd go with Postgres.